# Create Event Log source and write to it without administrative privileges

Tags: powershell

I'm running a Powershell logon script which sets users' Outlook signatures.

For debugging purposes, I'd like to log information in the client's Windows event log.

Using the `New-Eventlog -LogName "Application" -Source $ParentScript` command gives me a security error, "Access denied".

The users don't have administrative privileges so PowerShell is struggling to create a new source. I don't really understand this because most techy guides for the Event Log appear to indicate that any level of user can write to the Application log. Perhaps any user can write to this log, just not create a source within it?

I've looked online and one author appeared to suggest (unless I have misinterpreted) that creating an event log in registry could be an option: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/00a043ae-9ea1-4a55-8b7c-d088a4b08f09/how-do-i-create-an-event-log-source-under-vista?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Unfortunately the code is not in PowerShell and I'm struggling to follow it.

My three-questions-in-one therefore are:

- Can I create a new EventLog source in the registry using PowerShell?
- If so, what commands should I be looking at and are permissions relevant (e.g. do I need to create a registry key then add perms to it?)
- If so, can I write to this source in PowerShell without administrative privileges?

Comment: In the article you reference it states: _" to create an event source, you need to have read permission on this and all sub keys, and write permission on the event to which you want to create the event source"_, which makes sense - it would not be a great idea if a non-Admin could modify the setup of event logs.  Can't you set this up as an Admin, then normal users can write to the log later since the source will then exist?

Comment: That might be worth looking into boxdog - perhaps through Group Policy or something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Event Log souce with with the built-in cmelt New-EventLog something like there is a nice (even if somehow dated) post [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2014/03/29/create-event-log-sources-using-powershell/)

Full documentation for the cmdlet can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1)

Generally speaking yes you, well your user, should be able to write to the event log if memory serves a non local admin user should already be able to do so but I cannot test it right now anyhow you can red more [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028427/writing-to-the-windows-event-log-from-an-asp-net-or-asp-application-fa) or read on [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/823279/how-to-allow-a-domain-user-to-write-the-windows-event-log-2008-r2-or-newer-wit)

Hope this can help a bit.

Comment: I'm already using `New-EventLog`, as described in OP.

Your link gives me an indication as to how I can write to the relevance source by amending registry permissions, but I'm still no further forwards with regard to actually creating the source in the first place. Are you able to help with that?

Comment: Sorry I've now properly re-read your post, I should stop writing while doing other 3 things.

Maybe you can try something like? `[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource("Test",'Application')`

You'd still need permissions to read all logs though as it will check the new log source is unique.